# Dockerfile - how to RUN (execute) a script that is being passed in as an argument

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a project that uses Docker.  When the image is being built, we have a need to pass in a full, multi-line bash script as a dynamic argument, and for the Dockerfile to execute that script as part of the image build.  So for example, we'd have a variable named `S_VAR` whose contents are:

```
#!/bin/sh 

mkdir -p /home/new_dir
chmod 700 /home/new_dir
```

Then our build command is:

`docker build --build-arg S_VAR="$S_VAR" .`

In our Dockerfile currently, that gets saved to a local script and executed (and it works correctly), using the lines below:

```
ARG S_VAR
ENV S_VAR=$S_VAR
RUN mkdir /src

RUN echo "$S_VAR" > /src/temp_script.sh
RUN chmod +x /src/temp_script.sh
RUN if [ "$S_VAR" != "" ] ; then /src/temp_script.sh; fi
```

That feels really silly though - we have no need to actually keep the script around in a persisted file.  Is there a more efficient way to tell the Dockerfile to just run that variable as a script if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [eval](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/eval/) command?

```
ARG S_VAR
ENV S_VAR=$S_VAR
RUN mkdir /src

RUN eval $S_VAR
```

It will execute the variable, but won't do anything if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I have tried using `eval`, and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Is there any reason why you specify the /bin/sh interpreter in the variable? If not, try to remove it and use eval.

Comment: Just because it literally gets copied over by reading a bash script.